# How to print grid from function

Tags: python

Im trying to create 2 functions, one where I create the grid and one where I actually print out the grid but only the content in the grid(no brackets), but
im unsure of how to do it.

my code:

```
def create_grid(grid):    
    grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0]]


def print_grid (grid):
    print(create_grid(grid))
```

Output I want:

```
        0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _but im unsure of how to do it._ Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

```
def print_grid(grid):
    for sub_grid in grid:
        print()
        for item in sub_grid:
            print(item, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Weird you are passing arguments when you just need a `return` keyword

```
def create_grid():
    return [[0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0]]

def print_grid():
    for row in create_grid():
      print(*row)

print_grid()
```

`print(*row)` simplifies it by unpacking the list `row`.

Comment: Maybe make the grid a parameter of the function to present a more general example?

Answer (score 0):

Your `create_grid` function doesn't make the grid it creates accessible to its caller, and as written you need to call it with a `grid` argument that doesn't exist yet.  Instead, `create_grid` should take no arguments and `return` the grid.

To implement `print_grid` you could call `print` multiple times within nested loops, or you could use `join` to just turn the whole thing into one string and use a single call to `print`.

```
def create_grid():
    return [
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

def print_grid(grid):
    print("\n".join(
        " ".join(map(str, row))
        for row in grid
    ))

print_grid(create_grid())
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a grid in your format, (made in a function or elsewhere), you can do:

```
[print(*i) for i in grid]
```

So in a function:

```
In[0]:
grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]


def print_grid(g):
    [print(*i) for i in g]
    
print_grid(grid)

Out[0]:

0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Right now, your `create_grid` function is wonky because it isn't doing anything with the argument `grid` (it immediately overwrites it) and it also returns `None`.

So you would want to update your first function to actually functionally create and return the grid, which can then passed to `print_grid` (seen in the `create_grid` of other answers already posted on this Q).